# How to convert Web API project from EntityFramework.InMemory to using SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, in-memory-database

I use Microsoft tutorial to create simple Web API solution, which use "In Memory" database:

[Tutorial: Create a web API with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)

How to convert this solution to use an actual database? My database already exists, but I'm also open for solution by creating table(s) with database migration scripts.

For now I added a connection string to `appsettings.json` file, and believe that I need to

1. remove package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory`
2. add package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`
3. connect context to my database, by using connection string

So how to do step #3 - I don't know.

Currently I have this code in `Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<TodoContext>(opt =>  opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("TodoList"));
```

I uploaded code to: https://github.com/sam-klok/WebApiCore7

NuGet packages I have:

[image]

Comment: I'm absolutely stunned that there's a Microsoft tutorial advertising in-memory database.

Comment: @gert-arnold Gert Arnold, package description says it for testing. "In-memory database provider for Entity Framework Core (to be used for testing purposes)". Ironically I had some trouble converting it to normal database. Still there are many actual applications for In Memory databases, see here more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-database

Comment: That link is something completely different (to quote Monty Python). Anyway, it's not your fault, just mentioning it because it puts people on a wrong track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` you can see a new extension method called `UseSqlServer` on dbcontext options like this:

```cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<TodoContext>(opt =>
  opt.UseSqlServer("YourDatabase_ConnectionString"));
```

If you want to create migration for database first add this package

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`

and run this commands for creating migration files

```bash
#for visual studio
Add-Migration InitialCreate

#for .Net Cli
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
```

and for create or update database

```bash
#for visual studio
Update-Database

#for .Net Cli
dotnet ef database update
```

Comment: I didn't add Design package though and run add-migration, then update-database (run in certificate issue, solved it by adding TrustServerCertificate=True into connection string. I'm continue playing with it, thank you!

Comment: @samklok you're right, the design package is used when you want to use ``IDesignTimeDbContextFactory ``. Answer updated.